# Ruby Multiple Words Pig Latin

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble with a Ruby pig latin translator translating 2 or more words. I've successfully figured out how to translate words beginning with a vowel, consonant, or two consonants with my function translate, and I'm wanting to create a second function, translate_words, that uses .map with the first function.

When the string, "eat pie", gets submitted, the output is "eat pieay". It only changes the second word and also does it incorrectly (should be "eatay iepay"). I've looked at multiple other solutions on SO without luck. I'm still very new with regex so those solutions were a little over my head.

This project works with RSpec and I've added the test code below mine.

Here's my code:

```
def translate(input)
    pig_string = ''
    if input[0] =~ /[aeiou]/
        return input + 'ay'
    elsif input[0] =~ /[^aeiou]/ && input[1] =~ /[aeiou]/
        return input[1..-1] + input[0] + 'ay'
    elsif input[0..1] =~ /[^aeiou]/
        return input[2..-1] + input[0..1] + 'ay'
    else
        return input[0] + input + 'ay'
    end
end

def translate_words(multi_words)
    word_count = multi_words.split.size
    if word_count > 1
        multi_words.map! do |word|
            translate(word)
        end
    end
end
```

RSpec:

```
it "translates two words" do
  s = translate("eat pie")
  expect(s).to eq("eatay iepay")
end
```

Comment: Include your input, expected output and actual output in the code. Make it as easy to copy-paste-run-see as possible.

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine with one small change. Do `multi_words.split.map!` instead.

Comment: @bitsapien: "works absolutely fine" - well, almost. It doesn't do anything when string consists of one word. One word string is a special case of multi-word strings :)

Comment: You would need to `join` your array too I suspect.

Comment: @bitsapien thanks for the suggestion but it's still outputting "eat pieay". If it helps, I'm doing this as part of the Odin Project's Test-First Ruby Project here: https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/web-development-101/lessons/ruby?ref=lc-pb

Comment: Shouldn't your test say `s = translate_words`?

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks! I did tests in the past where the functions were differently named & still worked so I thought it was fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments above by bitsapien and Sergio Tulentsev :

```
def translate_words(multi_words)
  multi_words.split.map do |word|
    translate(word)
  end.join(' ')
end
```

`map` will suffice instead of `map!`.

```
translate_words('eat plie') #=> "eatay ieplay"
```

Comment: When would you need to use `map!` instead of `map`?. It doesn't look like that was able to pass the test & it's still outputting "eat pieay". If it helps, I'm doing this as part of the Odin Project's Test-First Ruby Project here: https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/web-development-101/lessons/ruby?ref=lc-pb

Comment: @IsaiahO: nope, it doesn't output "eat pieay". Must be you didn't copy it correctly or something.

Comment: @IsaiahO: also what does your test expect? A fully translated string, or array of translated words? Adjust code or test to match one another.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the RSpec file expects a fully translated string. It's so frustrating since I've tried altering the translate function & the multi word function but I keep getting "eat pieay" as the output.

Comment: @IsaiahO Use `map!` when you need to modify the object. There is no need in this case so just use `map`.

Comment: @IsaiahO Perhaps add the relevant tests to the question, may help (though i'm not familiar with RSpec, but someone else will be).